# Unable to set initialData in Streambuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Whenever I try to set initialData I get same error:

> The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>?

Note, no matter the type, if I try a number then says "type 'int'", or double, etc., is the same, if I try casting then I get:

> ... as is not a subtype of type 'DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>' in type cast

How can I set initialData in following code:

```
class PriceUpdaterWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const PriceUpdaterWidget({
    Key? key,
    required this.loginService,
    required this.code,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final LoginService loginService;
  final String? code;
  _PriceUpdaterWidgetState createState() => _PriceUpdaterWidgetState();
}

class _PriceUpdaterWidgetState extends State<PriceUpdaterWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('shoppers')
            .doc(widget.loginService.loggedInUserModel!.uid)
            .collection("cartItems")
            .doc(widget.code)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context,
            AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          SellerNameService isSellerName =
              Provider.of<SellerNameService>(context, listen: false);

          var sellerName = isSellerName.isSellerName;

          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            return Text(
              snapshot.data![sellerName].toStringAsFixed(2),
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            );
          } else {
            return Text('No Data');
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to set as initial value? Since you `StreamBuilder` returns data type `<DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>`, `initialData` also needs to be this type.